# C programming: parameter passing and return values

Tags: c

I was hoping I could get some input on what I think is a very simple C programming task.  I have been stuck on it for a couple days, and I assume the problem is an issue with basic parameter passing.

1. I have `conv_to_cent.c` program that has a `main()` in it.
2. This program makes a call to a library function `convert_to_cent` and passes in a parameter `double fahr`.  The library function is supposed to take a Fahrenheit temperature value and convert it to Celsius.
3. The library function receives the passed in value successfully, performs the calculation successfully, stores the result in a variable called `cent`, then attempts to return it using `return cent`.
4. This seems straightforward, but the value returned from my function does not match the value that is calculated within the function.
5. Does anyone know what would cause this problem or know what I am doing wrong?  Thanks so much for any assistance.

The following is my source and the 3 files that it is in:

#### conv_to_cent.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double fahr;
    fahr = 83.0;
    printf ("%3.1f degrees Fahrenheit is %3.1f degrees centigrade.\n",
         fahr, convert_to_cent(fahr));
    return 0;
}
```

#### cent_convert_header.h

```
double convert_to_cent (double fahr);
```

#### cent_convert.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cent_convert_header.h>

double convert_to_cent(double fahr)
{
    double cent;
    printf ("output from cent_convert: fahr passed in: %3.1f \n", fahr);

    /* perform the calculation to centigrade */
    cent = (5/(double)9) * (fahr-32);
    printf ("output from cent_convert: calculated value for cent is: %3.1f \n", cent);

    /* return the calculated value */
    return cent;
}
```

#### Output

```
output from cent_convert: fahr passed in: 83.0
output from cent_convert: calculated value for cent is: 28.3
output from main: 83.0 degrees Fahrenheit is 83.0 degrees centigrade.
```

Comment: please make up  your mind with the tags, there is not such things as C/C++

Comment: Shouldn't `conv_to_cent.c` have `#include <cent_convert_header.h>` at the top somewhere?

Comment: Have you omitted `#include "cent_convert_header.h"`? Without the function prototype, the compiler will assume the  `double` is `int`. What were the compiler warnings?

Comment: Indeed, clean (remove) your executable, compile again, report compiler warnings and errors.
(Apart from that, store the function result in a temporary double, report it)
Make a small change in output strings, to be sure the executable is updated.

Comment: That's odd.  Are you sure you're linking an up-to-date version of both modules?  What command are you using to compile your executable?

Comment: It is the missing include. Undefined behaviour.

Comment: this line: `cent = (5/(double)9) * (fahr-32);`  would be much better written as: `cent = (5.0/9.0) * (fahr-32.0);` so every thing is performed in 'double' without any conversions.

Comment: the file: conv_too_cent.c is missing the `#include "cent_convert_header.h"`  so the compiler makes assumptions/uses default parameter and return types (typically 'int') which makes both the calculation and the returned value wrong.

Comment: the header file is missing the 'include guards' which might not make any difference in this example, but will be a major problem in more complex projects

Comment: I would say it didn't compile properly (due to the missing include?!), and your re-testing an earlier compiled version where you returned fahr in convert_to_cent

Comment: this line: `/* conv_to_cent.c` is missing the trailing `*/`

Comment: Ignore the trailing */ remark, because the end of next line will serve as trailing */

Comment: Always compile with all warnings enabled.  Then the compiler would have told you about the implicit declaration of function 'convert_to_cent()' and the resulting problem with the 'printf' statement and the problem with the comment syntax

Comment: The -Wall recommendation is valid, but I still think without the #include, it would result in error on undefined symbol 'convert_to_cent' in...

Comment: @Pieter21,  Not true, embedding a '/*' inside another comment results in a compiler warning:  `conv_to_cent.c:3:1: warning: "/*" within comment [-Wcomment]`

Comment: @Pieter21,  Suggest you actually compile the posted code:

Comment: @Pieter21 No, the problem isn't a missing definition (that would be a linker error.) The code is probably being compiler in pre-C99 mode. See the comments with the word "implicit".

Comment: To get more than "all" warnings (in GCC; clang supports the same options), compile with `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic`.  `-Wall` does not really mean *all*.  See: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Comment: the line in  cent_convert.c: `#include "cent_convert_header.h"` is a problem (fatal error on my ubuntu linux 14.04) even though I compile with the '-I.' parameter.   the line should be: `#include "cent_convert_header.h"`  as '<' and '>' are for system headers while double quotes  are for user defined headers.  Note, I compile with the `std=c99` parameter.  C11 modified the default operation, making un-prototyped functions an error rather than a warning.

Answer (score 2):

As @WeatherVane suggested in his comment, your *conv_to_cent.c* file is missing an include for *cent_convert_header.h*.  This causes the compiler to assume that `convert_to_cent` returns an `int`, which it doesn't, so things break.

---

To elaborate a bit on what *could* happen (though this is pure speculation, as you have a case of undefined behaviour): my best guess as to why you get the result you do is that the second argument to `printf` is read from the floating point stack. The floating point stack seems to contain `fahr` multiple times, so both for the first and second `printf` argument its value is retrieved. In the mean time, the compiler pushed some phantom return value from `convert_to_cent` to `printf` as an `int`, but this value is never read because the call to `printf` contains no integer-specifier.

Comment: Thanks for the input everyone!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the missing header `#include` in your conversion routine, one thing you will want to get in the habit of doing is *wrapping* your header files with a simple `#ifndef` (`#if not defined`) call to a unique label you use to identify the header file. The purpose is to prevent multiple inclusion of your header file at compile time. (If you look at any of the standard header files, you will see it done)

To prevent multiple inclusion, you simply check whether there is an existing definition unique to that header, and if not, then create the `#define` and include the header contents. For example, with your `cent_convert.h` file:

**cent_convert.h**

```
#ifndef _cent_convert_h_
#define _cent_convert_h_  1

#include <stdio.h>

double convert_to_cent (double fahr);

#endif /* _cent_convert_h_ */
```

**Note:** reserve all capital include defines for the system, just make yours lower-case to insure there is no conflict. Also, give the define a value of `1` (or some positive number). While not 100% required, they technically should test `TRUE`.

The remaining flow of files is uneffected:

**cent_convert.c**

```
#include "cent_convert.h"

double convert_to_cent(double fahr)
{
    double cent;

    printf ("output from cent_convert: fahr passed in: %3.1f \n", fahr);

    /* perform the calculation to centigrade */
    cent = (5/(double)9) * (fahr-32);

    printf ("output from cent_convert: calculated value for cent is: %3.1f \n",
            cent);

    /* return the calculated value */
    return cent;
}
```

**f2c.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cent_convert.h"

int main (void)
{
    double fahr;
    fahr = 83.0;
    printf ("%3.1f degrees Fahrenheit is %3.1f degrees centigrade.\n",
        fahr, convert_to_cent(fahr));

    return 0;
}


/*
    // Compile
    gcc -Wall -Wextra -Ofast cent_convert.c -o bin/f2c f2c.c

    // Run
    $ ./bin/f2c
    output from cent_convert: fahr passed in: 83.0
    output from cent_convert: calculated value for cent is: 28.3
    83.0 degrees Fahrenheit is 28.3 degrees centigrade.

*/
```

Comment: regarding this statement: "reserve all capital include defines for the system, just make yours lower-case to insure there is no conflict"   Upper case is just fine.  avoid the use of a leading underscore.  Using the trailing '1' is not needed as the check is for 'is it defined', not what is its' current value